# Etag not appearing in header in Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel, api, etag

I am using Laravel 5.7 to build an API (authenticated with Passport) with some middleware to send an `ETag` in the header. The middleware looks like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (!$request->isMethod('get')) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    $response = $next($request);

    $currentEtag = DB::table('etag')->first()->etag;

    $response->setEtag($currentEtag);

    return $response;
}
```

But when I make a `GET` request to a controller with this middleware applied, there is no `ETag` key in the response headers. I know the middleware is being called (by inserting a `dd` command in it). My response headers look like this:

```
Date: Mon, 08 Oct 2018 10:18:21 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25 (Debian)
Cache-Control: private, must-revalidate
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 59
Vary: Authorization
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
```

EDIT:

I am also using [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) middleware. In the config file I have:

```
'supportsCredentials' => false,
'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
'allowedOriginsPatterns' => [],
'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
'exposedHeaders' => ['ETag'],
'maxAge' => 0,
```

Comment: Did you try`$response->header('Etag', $currentEtag)`.


https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#attaching-headers-to-responses

Comment: @Remul This produces the same result.

Comment: @GluePear can you remove `laravel-cors` middleware from the request you are testing and tell us if that fixed the issue? If so, then you need to extend the laravel-cors middleware and add etag there or make sure your middleware is called latter

Comment: @NikolaGavric Thanks. I removed the `laravel-cors` middleware, but it made no difference.

Comment: Are you sure that the etag value is being returned and not-null from that eloquent query? If the etag value is null, `setEtag()` will remove the header.

Comment: @AaronSaray Yes, I `dd`'d it.